# Docker Push keeps on retrying for large file

Tags: docker, dockerfile, docker-registry

I am using Windows and Docker for Desktop. I've a jar with 178MB and one with 100MB in 2 different projects. When I do push to remote registry, all other layers are being pushed successfully. But the layer with Jar shows progress till 100% and then retries.

This retry happen again and again. Gives `unexpected EOF` at the end and fails.

I tried finding the issue in docker issues but didn't solve the problem.

[image: Snapshort]

Comment: This seems likely to be a problem in your network setup, or possibly your registry; it doesn't seem like it's a programming-related problem or something the community could solve.  I've run into similar troubles in the past, but with individual layers more like 1 GB, and retrying would lead to failure at a different point (or very occasionally success).

Comment: @Mansoor do you happen to fix this?

Comment: @utopictown. No!

Comment: @Mansoor in my case its just my internet issue